# HTML Submit Button Not Functioning

Tags: html

I searched around, but I didn't see my particular issue. Basically, I want to create a form on my website that will send, as an email, to my address. When I try to click submit, nothing happens. I have searched around, but I cannot find my error.

```
<form method="post" action="mailto:myemail">
      Name: <input style="position: relative; left:25px;" type="text" name="name" />
  <br />
  Email: <input style="position: relative; left:27px;" type="text" name="email" />
  <br />
  Message: 
  <br />
  <textarea style="position: relative; left: 85px;" cols="30" rows = "10"></textarea>
  <br />
       <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your form's action uses a `mailto:` scheme. This has [so many problems](http://isolani.co.uk/articles/mailto.html) that it can be considered to "just not work".

You need an HTTP (or HTTPS) URI with a server side form handler.

Comment: I am seeing a lot of suggestions saying I have to use PHP, should I go that route?

Comment: If you aren't going to use a third party service, then your choice of server side language is dependent on personal preference and what your server supports. PHP is one of the most widely supported server side languages, but isn't to my taste.

Comment: @Oni that depends. You can use any server-side language: PHP, Perl, Ruby, Java, Javascript(Node.js). Most common (in non-commercial environments) is PHP though.

Comment: I am only "well-versed" in CSS and HTML. I wanted to add one of those languages to my skillset, but which is the "best" and most versatile? I see you mention PHP is the most common, but I have always been suggested to learn Javascript.

Comment: "best" is subjective, and there is little to choose between them for versatility (and language choices are off-topic for SO). If you want to learn JavaScript, then learn JavaScript (but note you will need a server side implementation (such as node.js), not a client side one).

Comment: Gotcha. I'll do my research on that then. Thanks for the direction.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this with HTML.
What you need is a php script that is able to send emails.
The only way in which you could open a mail dialog would be `<a href="mailto:myemail@gmail.com"></a>`
Take a look at this website :
http://email.about.com/od/emailprogrammingtips/qt/How_to_Send_Email_from_a_PHP_Script.htm

Answer (score 0):

you can't use `mailto:` as a forms target address that easy (and it won't ever just "send the mail" and open ther users mail-client instead). please [start reading on that again](http://www.labnol.org/internet/email/learn-mailto-syntax/6748/) ([especially about forms](http://isolani.co.uk/articles/mailto.html)) and start over.

Answer (score 0):

To send emails, you need to use PHP for example. Did you already try it?[manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php)

Answer (score 0):

You should not use a mailto-Link as the `action` for a form. `action` usually expects a server-side script that the form will use to process the data.

There are tons of tutorials out there that will explain how to build a contact form, so maybe you should read one of those. This is the first one that I found: http://www.phpjabbers.com/make-contact-form-and-send-email-in-php-php21.html (in case you are able to run PHP on your server)

Comment: Thanks for the link. I'll give this one a try. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

First of all: mailto as action is valid! Add `enctype="text/plain"`.

Note, that you have no guarantee of success!! It depends on the browser and setting of the client whether your mail will be sent or not.

It's saver to submit the form to your server and send serverside.

Comment: Could you tell me what kind of configuration you need for that to work? It does not on my machine and I have no clue where to find a setting like this?

Comment: Your client-browser needs to know how to handle the `mailto:` protocoll, he needs a mailclient and so on... If you have no control over your clients (e.g. a companies intranet), I definitely recommend you, to use the normal way: Submit your form to your server, and send the mail server-side. How to do that depends on your server-configuration. Read some of the links, the other posters  provided. This should give you a starting point.

Comment: thanks for the links, don't worry I won't use that as I'd be able to handle a PHP based solution, I just didn't even know this was possible.

Comment: Okay, I hope this helped you a little;)

Answer (score 0):

Forms should be used for sending data to another file on the server. The action field you use should only specify the path to which we need to send the data.

Answer (score 0):

If you give the textarea a name (like `name="message"`) and users click the submit button a local client might open. The content of the form will be displayed as `name=roger&email=myemail%40gmail.com&mesage=test+from+browser`.

But I agree with most answers that it is a much better way to handle the email on a server